# c# system.windows.input.keyboard unresponsive with certain programs

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard, windows-11

I'm running a program which scan a tag and output the value to the keyboard.
This works perfectly in windows 10, but in windows 11 it work in some programs but not in others.
If I try to get the input to notepad, it works. If I try to get it to notepad++, it does not.

It seems to me to be a windows setting, but I get no error messages and there's nothing in the log files.

If anyone know of any solutions or have any ideas on what I can try, I'd be overjoyed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a windows feature UIPI (User Interface Privilege Isolation). I you do not run the writing program as admin, it cannot output to programs which run as admin.